# Create a custom onChange function as a parameter for a component in react, which takes 2 custom arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

This is hard to explain with words, but if you look at the code in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-double-slider-with-colors-and-labels-forked-deerr), you might understand. I am trying to create this slider component, and want the onChange function for the component to be able to access both the min and the max value of the slider.

This way you could create the slider, and access the min and the max like

```
<Slider
        min={300}
        max={3000}
        onChange={(nMin, nMax) => {
          setNewMin(nMin);
          setNewMax(nMax);
        }}
      />
```

This is similar to the onChange and onChangeComitted functions for the [material ui slider](https://material-ui.com/components/slider). I'm wondering how I could create arguments like these myself.

---

To recap, I want to know how I could update the code in the codesandbox, so that the newMin, and newMax can be accessed within the App component. Right now the nMin, and nMax aren't actually assigned values.

Comment: The sandbox link goes to material docs

Comment: @charlietfl fixed

Comment: Just declare it in the parent and pass it down to the slider. Each slider component knows its own min/max.

Comment: @pilchard I'm not trying to do that. I'm trying to create a slider with an onChange which is similar to the material ui slider's onChange

Comment: @charlietfl How does material ui do it then?

Comment: Looks like material ui just accepts a standard onChange callback to which it passes the event and the new value or array of values `function(event: object, value: number | number[]) => void`. So you simply need to forward the event and new value to whatever callback gets passed down from the parent.

Comment: @pilchard Do you know of some example code for something that does this?

Comment: I think I might have figured out where you are stuck. Is it that you aren't sure how to pass a function into `onChange` to use in the component instance?

Comment: @charlietfl Maybe? I'm not sure what you mean exactly

Comment: Give me a few minutes will work on it

Comment: See if this is along the lines of what you are looking for. It's a bit rough but gives you more args in the App onChange https://codesandbox.io/s/react-double-slider-with-colors-and-labels-forked-jf0uz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, that's easier than I expected

Comment: Might be cleaner to pass an object back rather than multiple arguments. Also with some fine tuning probably only need one `handleChange` for both inputs. i just copied one to create the other quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with any callback the arguments are determined by the function that actually calls it

```js
function foo(callback){
   const a = 1, b = 2, c = {foo:'bar'};
   //you determine what arguments are when calling the callback
   callback(a , b, c);   
}

function myCallback(arg1, arg2, arg3){
   console.log('Arg2 =', arg2)
}

foo(myCallback)
```

So think of the onChange prop of your component as a callback. You use the event listeners in the component to call the callback passed into props

Simplified example

```js
const Slider = ({value, onChange}) => {
  // handles the change on actual element 
  const handleChange =({target})=>{    
    if(typeof onChange === 'function'){
       // call the callback passing in whatever parameters you decide
       // in this simple case just sending numeric value
       onChange(target.valueAsNumber)
    }    
  }
  return  (<input value={value} type="range" onChange={handleChange} min="1" max="10" />);
};

const App = ()=>{
   const [val, setVal] = React.useState(4);
   // only receives value as documented by the Slider component
   const handleChange = (value) => setVal(value);
   return (
     <div>
      <div>Value in App: {val}</div>
      <Slider value={val} onChange={handleChange}/>
    </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```