# How to pass values from on react component to another using states?

Tags: reactjs

I am starting to learn react and after a taking an online course I decided to test myself and build an example.

**What's my goal**
I have a form which is returning an object with the values I enter in the input fields:

```
//Form component
const Form = () => {

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      age: "",
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <UnderlinedText>Form</UnderlinedText>
      <ProfileForm onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <Label htmlFor="name">Name:</Label>
        <Input
          id="name"
          type="text"
          autoComplete="off"
          value={formik.values.name}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />
        <Label htmlFor="age" autoComplete="off">
          Age:
        </Label>
        <Input
          id="age"
          type="text"
          autoComplete="off"
          value={formik.values.age}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />
        <SubmitButton type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </ProfileForm>
    </>
```

I want to render it in this component:

```
const UserInfo = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header2>Name:</Header2>
      <Content>{{name}}</Content>
      <Header2>Age:</Header2>
      <Content>{{age}}</Content>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

What would be the way to pass the information from one component to the other without using fetches to the API?

Comment: You need to host the state in a parent component, which wraps your form and the `UserInfo` component and passes down the state to both components.

Comment: ^ That answer is probably best, there's also redux(you would probably want `redux-form` in this case), or (don't do this) [you could use a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67117558/create-a-custom-onchange-function-as-a-parameter-for-a-component-in-react-which) (but you shouldn't)

Comment: Thank you both @PeterLehnhardt is there a way you can write what you mean in codepen please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share state between components the state must be hosted by a parent component, which renders both child components and passes state and change handlers to both child components. An example is given [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-fast-ebcr1?file=/src/index.js).